# What is the canonical way to play the missions?

Tags: lego-batman-3

After you finish the mission Big Trouble in Little Gotham, a few missions will become available: "Power of Love", "A Blue Hope", "Need for Greed", "All The Rage" and "Jailhouse Nok". Which mission should be played first according to the storyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Steam Achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/313690/achievements) page, Power of Love is first, A Blue Hope is second, Jailhouse Nok is third, All the Rage is fourth, Need for Greed is fifth and Aw-Qward
 Situation is the last "lantern" mission.